# Full GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am struggling to hunt down the "Full GC" on our production JVM. Every day at around midnight the STW occurs without apparent reason, quite deadly for 10-11 sec. Here is the gc log:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 16584284k(13074876k free), swap 23137624k(18439472k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:GCLogFileSize=1024000 -XX:InitialHeapSize=11811160064 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=11811160064 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC 
...
2020-01-17T00:00:04.411+0200: 113734.053: [GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 522474K->146371K(3387904K)] 6946079K->6573263K(11077632K), 0.1786961 secs] [Times: user=0.67 sys=0.02, real=0.18 secs] 
2020-01-17T00:00:04.592+0200: 113734.233: [Full GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 146371K->0K(3387904K)] [ParOldGen: 6426892K->3217828K(7689728K)] 6573263K->3217828K(11077632K), [Metaspace: 81937K->81809K(1126400K)], 11.4447857 secs] [Times: user=44.06 sys=0.20, real=11.44 secs]
```

What **"Heap Inspection Initiated GC"** actually means? Who initiates this inspection and why? I've failed to find any meaningful information about it other than it gets caused by some tools like jmap, jmc.. which we don't use.

Any hint or direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: don't get me wrong, but you are using a `ParallelGC` and wonder why you get a large STW? just wondering...

Comment: Yes, this is ParallelGC. The question actually was -what "Heap Inspection Initiated GC" cause actually means. Obviously the cause is not lack of heap and need to clean up. There is plenty of heap in this VM.

Comment: you have to tag me with `@` for me to know that you responded. Do you have may be  an agent that does that? may be [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/services/attachListener.cpp#l354) is triggered?

Comment: @Eugene - OK, this rings the bell.. We use [this](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/perfino/overview.html) for monitoring. I am going to check this out. If I understand correctly, this GC may have been caused by an external process and not by itself? Is that what this cause means?

Comment: exactly. there are various places as far as I can see where this can be triggered: an agent, jmap, jfr, `SIGBREAK`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JVM` agent can trigger a [heap inspection too](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/services/attachListener.cpp#l354). To know the liveness of Objects at the current moment, you need to trigger a `Full GC` call. I guess in cases of `Shenandoah` and/or `ZGC` this would be a lot "cheaper", since they work concurrently with your application. What is even more interesting, that in theory at least, a concurrent `GC` does not need to trigger *all* of the phases (`mark` would be enough) to find what is live and/or dead. However, I doubt that they don't do `compaction` *also*.

If you really care about `STW` events, `ParallelGC` might not be a very good option to begin with. `Parallel` in the name of the garbage algorithm should ring a bell: all of its phases are parallel to the application; *not* concurrent.

Comment: Thank you for the lead! Problem was wound - the agent ("perfino" in our case). It had the one of the defaults (**Record periodic heap snapshots**) set to 24 hours. Which resulted in Full GC at monitored JVM every midnight. Bad idea. @Ingo Kegel - FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Spectator Docs - GC Causes](https://netflix.github.io/spectator/en/latest/ext/jvm-gc-causes/):

> #### Heap_Inspection_Initiated_GC
>
> GC was initiated by an inspection operation on the heap. For example you can trigger this with [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html):
>
> ```
> $ jmap -histo:live <pid>
> ```

See also [Does JMC Flight Recording force Full GC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43757177/5221149) (answer: yes, if Heap Statistics enabled)
See also [Will `jcmd PID GC.class_histogram` call a full GC before collecting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48446767/5221149) (answer: yes)

Comment: Thank you, I saw these.. but we don't use any external processes to trigger the GC on running VM.

Comment: @Dima You were obviously [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803823/full-gc-heap-inspection-initiated-gc/59804135?noredirect=1#comment105750788_59804893) about that.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong because I didn't realize that profiler agent is capable of doing this.

Comment: JFR doesn't cause a full GC unless you explicitly enable Heap Statistics, or you dump a recoding with jcmd <pid> JFR.dump path-to-gc-roots=true.

Comment: @KireHaglin Yes, that is exactly what the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766428/5221149) says, so what's your point?

Comment: Just want to clarify. "answer: yes" was put there (I assume) to help people who do not follow the link.