# Java Garbage Collection after heap memory crosses a threshold

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, java-heap

Is it possible to invoke a forceful garbage collection in java every time heap memory crosses a particular threshold ?

Comment: I know this isn't overly helpful but maybe you should find out why your application is using so much memory and then try and reduce it if possible, or provide more memory.

Comment: Why? What's the point of doing that? What do you know that the JVM doesn't, that you "know better" when the GC needs to run?

Comment: @Andreas though far stretched, but how about a report generation that takes a lot of time? What you would not want is more time introduced by a potential Full GC, so trigger a Full GC _before_ the report generation. I guess there could be other cases too - as there are tools that actually give you that ability. If there are tools that do that, there are people that need that, I guess.

Comment: @Eugene The question isn't about triggering at some particular *point* in the code, e.g. before a report, which is already supported ([`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--)), but about triggering on heap memory use threshold, i.e. to trigger a full GC when heap is e.g. 30% full, instead of letting the JVM decide for itself when partial and full GCs should be done. So I'm asking OP what the point is. Why would that be an improvement over the JVMs built-in logic, which has undergone lots of testing to be fine-tuned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *already* happens. For example in `G1GC`, this is either when young space is full (for a minor collection) or when `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent` is hit (for a major collection). Both of these are controlled via flags, so you can tell when *exactly* is a GC supposed to be triggered, IFF you really want that.

In `Shenandoah` there is `ShenandoahGCHeuristics` that will choose some heuristics (they do depend on the size too).

If, on the the other hand, you want to do that programmatically (there are tools that do that already), you could write some code that would inspect the size of the heap (for example via `ManagementFactory::getMemoryPoolMXBeans`) and then  [via an agent call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803823/full-gc-heap-inspection-initiated-gc/59804893#59804893). In general, you would need a *very* good reason to do this.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but isn't InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent set to default at 45%

Comment: @Jaharsh did I name any other number?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, you could configure such behaviour. Exact details depend on used garbage collection alghoritm. For example, for CMS you can kick off GC when heap memory usage reaches 70%. Most probably you would also want to set initial and max memory limits.

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `CMS` is deprecated and dead, FYI