# Zig-zag heap memory patterns in Akka http scala service

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, akka, newrelic

I've a AKKA-HTTP based service which is written in scala. This service works as a proxy for an API call. It creates a host connection pool for calling API using
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html

The service is integrated with NewRelic and has the attached snapshots[image: NewRelic snapshot]

[image: NewRelic]

I would like to understand the reasons for this kind of zig-zag patterns even when there is no traffic on the service and the connections in the host-pool gets terminated because of idle-timeout.

Moreover, I would also like to know Does the FULL GC will only occur after it reached a threshold say 7GB? or it can also occur at some other time when there is no traffic?

The service has XmX of 8GB. Moreover, there are also multiple dispatchers(fork-join-executor) which performs multiple tasks.

Answer (score 4):

First, your graphs show a very healthy application. This "chainsaw" pattern is overall seen as a very good thing, without much to worry about.

When exactly a Full GC is going to happen is a bit hard to predict (I would use the word impossible, too). When your "live" objects have nowhere to move (because there is simply no space for that), a `Full GC` may be triggered. There are certain thresholds of when a *concurrent* phase (marking) is going to be initiated, but if that results in a `Full GC` or not is decided later.

Considering that `G1` also re-sizes regions (makes them less/more) based on heuristics, and the fact that it can also shrink or grow your heap (up to `-Xmx`), the exact conditions when a Full GC might happen is not easy to predict (I guess some GC experts that know the exact internal details might be able to do that). Also, `G1GC` can do partial collections: when it collects young regions + some of the old regions (not all), still making it far better than a `Full GC` time-wise.

Unfortunately, your point about no traffic is correct. When there is very limited traffic, you might not get a `Full GC`, but immediately as traffic comes in, such a thing might happen. Old regions might slowly build up during your "limited traffic" and as soon as you have a spike - surprise. There are [ways to trigger a Full GC on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803823/full-gc-heap-inspection-initiated-gc), and though I have heard of such applications that do this - I have not worked with one in practice.

Comment: AFAIK, the objects will build up in the heap memory only when request hits the server. And as the servers were idle(no request was being served, confirmed), why does the heap memory usage shows zig-zag pattern? I'm a bit confused here as when all the requests are being served, Minor GC will mark and clean or push to Old gen and then the heap size should show a less consistent value as no objects(long arrays/timers) are being used which should hold the space for so long. Please clarify.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh if indeed there were no requests at all and your app was idle, I cant answer why you see zig-zags. It means someone _is_ allocating. Your application, you will have to figure out who does that.

Answer (score 3):

In general with a GC that's not reference-counting, you'll see that zig-zag pattern because memory is only reclaimed when a GC runs.

G1 normally only collects areas of the heap where it expects to find a lot of garbage relative to live objects ("garbage collection" is a bit of a misnomer: it actually involves collecting the live objects and (in the case of a relocating garbage collector like G1) moving the live objects to a different area of the heap, which allows the area it collected in to then be declared ready for new allocations; therefore the fewer live objects it needs to handle, the less work it needs to do relative to the memory freed up).

At a high-level, G1 works by defining an Eden (a young generation) where newly created objects where newly created objects are allocated and it divides Eden into multiple regions with each thread being mapped to a region.  When a region fills up, only that region is collected, with the survivors being moved into an older generation (this is simplifying).  This continues until the survivor generation is full, at which point the survivor and eden generations are collected, with the surviving survivors being promoted to the old generation, and when the old generation fills up, you have a full GC.

So there isn't necessarily a fixed threshold where a full GC will get triggered, but in general the more heap gets used up, the more likely it becomes that a full GC will run.  Beyond that, garbage collectors on the JVM tend to be more or less autonomous: most will ignore `System.gc` and/or other attempts to trigger a GC.

Conceivably with G1, if you allocated a multi-GiB array at startup, threw away the reference, and then after every period of idleness reallocated an array of the same size as the one you allocated at startup and then threw away the reference, you'd have a decent chance of triggering a full GC.  This is because that array is big enough to bypass eden and go straight to the old generation where it will consume heap until the next full GC.  Eventually there won't be enough contiguous free space in the old generation to allocate these arrays, and that will trigger a full GC.  The only complications to this approach are that:

- You'll eventually have to outsmart the JIT optimizer, which will see that you're allocating this array and throwing it away and decide that it doesn't actually have to allocate the array
- If you have a long enough busy time that a full GC ran since the last allocate-and-throw-away, there's no guarantee that the allocation of the large array will succeed after a full GC, which will cause an OOM.

Comment: "you have a full GC" - G1 tries not to do this as much as possible. It has one more "phase" called partial, where young is collected + _some_ old regions.